# Rebuses with answers that start with "A"

Tags: wordplay, rebus

I like rebuses, here are four of them.

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

4.[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:

> **An elephant never forgets.** (An + reorder "elepath" and <sub>7</sub>N (nitrogen) by the numbers next to the letters, + reuse N + ever + for:ts (I hope I'll find the "ge" soon.)

2:

> **A friend in need is a friend indeed.** (interpreting the mixing of letters as one word being inside the other)

3:

> **All bark and no bite** (All + "B arc" with negated "bit + e")

4:

> **A dime a dozen** (should be self-explanatory.)